# Grouping Rows Together

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a column with 14-character alpha/numeric data. I want to group rows together based on the first 7 characters.  Is this possible, in particular without VBA?

For example, if I have this data, I'd want to combine it into only 4 rows:

114060A30B9720
114200A12B7019
114200A19B7019
114200A57B7019
114234417B7019
11423445CB7019
114234469B7019
11423448CB7019
115200A11B7219
115200A30B7219
115200A60B7219

Answer (score 2):

Based on Excel 2007, but I think should suit: Copy your column (say to a new sheet starting in `A2`). Put `=LEFT(A2,7)` in `B2` and copy down. Select ColumnB and Copy/Paste Special/Values over the top. Advanced Filter, Copy to another location, Copy to:`C1` and check Unique records only. Delete ColumnsA:B.

Comment: Of if you need the extra bits but want everything grouped, follow the above steps but don;t paste special.  Use the Data-> Group or Subtotal commands.